# Why the performance of combine7 is better than combine5?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, algorithm, visual-c++, stl

**I test the following 7 functions, I can't understand why combine7 is better than combine5. Since they are different only in the position of "()".**

Anybody can explain them to me?

Here's my code:

```
#include "Common.h"

#define PLUS
#ifdef PLUS
#define INDENT 0
#define OP +
#else
#define INDENT 1
#define OP *
#endif
typedef int data_t;
typedef struct
{
    long int len;
    data_t *data;
}vec_rec, *vec_ptr;
vec_ptr new_vec(long int len)
{
    vec_ptr result = (vec_ptr)malloc(sizeof(vec_rec));  //Allocate header structure
    if(!result) return NULL;
    result->len = len;
    if(len > 0)     //Allocate array
    {
        data_t* data = (data_t*)calloc(len, sizeof(data_t));
        if(!data)
        {
            free((void*)result);
            return NULL;
        }
        result->data = data;
    }
    else result->data = NULL;
    return result;
}
int get_vec_element(vec_ptr v, long int index, data_t * dest)
{
    if(index < 0 || index >= v->len) return 0;
    *dest = v->data[index];
    return 1;
}
long int vec_length(vec_ptr v)
{
    return v->len;
}
data_t* get_vec_start(vec_ptr v)
{
    return v->data;
}

void combine5(vec_ptr v, data_t* dest)  
{
    long int i;
    long int length = vec_length(v);
    long int limit = length - 1;
    data_t* data = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t acc = INDENT;

    for(i = 0; i < limit; i += 2)
    {
        acc = (acc OP data[i]) OP data[i + 1];  
    }
    for(; i < length; i++)
        acc = acc OP data[i];
    *dest = acc;
}

void combine7(vec_ptr v, data_t* dest)
{
    long int i;
    long int length = vec_length(v);
    long int limit = length - 1;
    data_t* data = get_vec_start(v);
    data_t acc = INDENT;

    for(i = 0; i < limit; i += 2)
    {
        acc = acc OP (data[i] OP data[i + 1]);
    }
    for(; i < length; i++)
        acc = acc OP data[i];
    *dest = acc;
}

std::mt19937 gen;
int roll_die() {

    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1, 6);

    return dist(gen);

}

int main()
{
    const size_t len = 10000000;
    auto vec_pointer = new_vec(len);

    std::generate(vec_pointer->data, vec_pointer->data + vec_pointer->len, roll_die);
    std::cout << "Initialized datas..." << std::endl;
    /*std::copy(vec_pointer->data, vec_pointer->data + vec_pointer->len, 
        std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\t"));*/

    data_t dest = 0;

    utility::CStopwatch stopwatch5;
    combine5(vec_pointer, &dest);
    std::cout << "combine5 elapsed time(microseconds): " << stopwatch5.NowInMicro() << std::endl;

    utility::CStopwatch stopwatch7;
    combine7(vec_pointer, &dest);
    std::cout << "combine7 elapsed time(microseconds): " << stopwatch7.NowInMicro() << std::endl;
}
```

And here is my result:

```
Initialized datas...
combine5 elapsed time(microseconds): 16934
combine7 elapsed time(microseconds): 14858
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question.  There are (7 2) answers to this.

Comment: Guess 6 has a typo? Sholdn't it be `acc0 = acc0 OP data[i]; 
        acc1 = acc1 OP data[i+1];`?

Comment: What level of optimization are you using? I would think that the timing difference would be less in some cases with proper optimization (e.g. loop unrooling). BUt maybe I expect to much form compilers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`acc = (acc OP data[i]) OP data[i + 1];`  is naturally slower than
`acc = acc OP (data[i] OP data[i + 1]);`

Because in the first case you try to access data elements data[i] and data[i+1] in different operations and it results in a significant overhead while in the 2nd case you try to access them at the same time with the operation of  `(data[i] OP data[i + 1])` because they are neighbouring memory locations and iterating through each other is relatively faster than accessing them in separate instants.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really interested in finding out what makes the different functions perform differently, it could be an idea, to analyse the assembly code produced by the compiler. The functions are sufficiently simple to be readable in assembly, even by one not normally comfortable with this.

**In function 3** you dereference in each iteration:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i ++)
{
    *dest = *dest OP data[i];   
}
```

**In function 4**, you only dereference at the end:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i ++)
{
    acc = acc OP data[i];
}
*dest = acc;
```

**Function 5**, is faster since it only iterates half the number of iterations. See: [Loop unwinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unwinding)

Comment: I still wonder why the dereferencing makes a difference, I thought an optimizing compiler would just use a register for the addition inside the loop, and write the result back at the end of the loop/function?

Comment: @ted The optimizer can do a lot, but since we are not told anything about the optimization level, I think the dereferencing seems like a logical culprit. My sample assembly output from MSVC2010 showed that without optimizations enabled, it did make a difference to move the dereferencing outside the loop. But yes, it should be a minor change, and really only visible when build without optimisations. :)

Answer (score 0):

It's not so clear why these should be much different (certainly the explanation by fatih_k does not convince me). As your operator is commutative, the compiler may want to change the order anyway (depending on the compiler flags). Did you experiment with different compiler flags (in particular optimisation flags) and different compilers (clang, gcc, icpc)?

Also, how does the following form of the loop body fare?

```
 {
    acc *= data[i];
    acc *= data[i+1];
 }
```

A side note: avoid those crappy macros. Write templated code instead.